# i'm getting this error when running the below pyflink code

Tags: python, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

this is the code for calculating average of each ch[x] from a kafka source using apache flink(pyflink)
i think i have imported all of the necessary libraries

And I'm getting this error when running the code

```py
from numpy import average
from pyflink.table import TableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, TimeCharacteristic
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, DataTypes, EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.table.udf import udf
from pyflink.table import *

def create_input():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE input(
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3),
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'energymeter.raw',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '192.168.0.34:9092',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
          'format' = 'json',
        )
    """
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def average_power(x):
  return x*12*2
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def energy_consumption(x):
  return x/500
def create_output():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE output (
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `ch1_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch2_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch3_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch4_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch5_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch6_mod` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka'
          'topic' = 'energymeter.processed',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '192.168.0.34:9092',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
    """
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)
table_env.execute_sql(create_input())
table_env.execute_sql(average_power())
table_env.execute_sql(energy_consumption())
table_env.execute_sql(create_output())
table_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO output SELECT gw_id, t, ch1, average_power(ch1), ch2, average_power(ch2), ch3, average_power(ch3), ch4, average_power(ch4), ch5, average_power(ch5), ch6, average_power(ch6) FROM input").wait()
```

Error is this i have added sql kafka connector flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.14.4.jar but nothing seems to work

````
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered ")" at line 11, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    "CONSTRAINT" ...
    "PRIMARY" ...
    "UNIQUE" ...
    "WATERMARK" ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    
        at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.convertException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:472)
        at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.normalizeException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmtList(SqlParser.java:195)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseSqlList(CalciteParser.java:77)
        ... 13 more ```
````

Comment: You have extra commas after your field list and your WITH list.  Not allowed in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your program, e.g.

- Missing comma after `'connector' = 'kafka'`, extra comma after ``t `TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3),` and `'format' = 'json',`
- Should use `create_temporary_function` to register Python UDFs instead of `execute_sql`
- The fields order appearing in the `SELECT` clause is not consistent with the sink table `output` definition

I have made some modifications to it as following:

```
from numpy import average
from pyflink.table import TableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, TimeCharacteristic
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, DataTypes, EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.table.udf import udf
from pyflink.table import *

def create_input():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE input(
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'energymeter.raw',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '192.168.0.34:9092',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
    """
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def average_power(x):
  return x*12*2

@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def energy_consumption(x):
  return x/500

def create_output():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE output (
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `ch1_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch2_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch3_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch4_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch5_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch6_mod` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'energymeter.processed',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '192.168.0.34:9092',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
    """
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)
table_env.execute_sql(create_input())
table_env.create_temporary_function("average_power", average_power)
table_env.create_temporary_function("energy_consumption", energy_consumption)
table_env.execute_sql(create_output())
table_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO output SELECT gw_id, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6, average_power(ch1), average_power(ch2), average_power(ch3), average_power(ch4), average_power(ch5), average_power(ch6), t FROM input").wait()
```